# Trying to get a login to last 10 days

Tags: php

I'm using a login system, and I'm trying to keep the user logged in for 10 days unless they specifically log out.  I thought by using `session_set_cookie_params('864000');` that it would make the user stay logged in for 10 days.  But it's not doing that, at least in Chrome.  The user only seems to be logged in for the standard 20-30 minutes before being automatically logged out.  When I check the cookies in Chrome, there are two PHP Session cookies listed for my URL with expiration dates 10 days into the future.  But this seems to be unrelated to the login variables.  Most of the relevant code should be below.

Any idea why the user is not logged in for 10 days?

Thanks in advance,

John

In the index file, I have the following:

```
require_once "header.php"; 
 //content
 include "login.php";
```

In the header.php file, the following is included:

```
session_set_cookie_params('864000');
session_start();
```

In the login.php file, the following is included:

```
if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();


        }
```

Here is the function "checkLogin":

```
function checkLogin($u, $p)
{
global $seed; // global because $seed is declared in the header.php file

    if (!valid_username($u) || !valid_password($p) || !user_exists($u))
    {
        return false; // the name was not valid, or the password, or the username did not exist
    }

    //Now let us look for the user in the database.
    $query = sprintf("
        SELECT loginid 
        FROM login 
        WHERE 
        username = '%s' AND password = '%s' 
        AND disabled = 0 AND activated = 1 
        LIMIT 1;", mysql_real_escape_string($u), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($p . $seed)));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    // If the database returns a 0 as result we know the login information is incorrect.
    // If the database returns a 1 as result we know  the login was correct and we proceed.
    // If the database returns a result > 1 there are multple users
    // with the same username and password, so the login will fail.
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        // Login was successfull
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // Save the user ID for use later
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $row['loginid'];
        // Save the username for use later
        $_SESSION['username'] = $u;
        // Now we show the userbox
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks more likely that your server is discarding the sessions -- you'd need to store pertinent information in a local friendly database and load from there, based on the cookies as appropriate